# java runnable file with sql db file

Tags: java, sql

I have been looking around for a simple & straightforward solution. I have an Eclipse runnable jar file (executable) & a exported SQL data file. these 2 files will be opened at another computer, which does not have any form of support. How can I run the application with all the population of data via the DB file? Do I have to do it by code or is there a simpler way out that I may have missed?

Comment: And DBMS are you using? You can only do that with an embedded one like HSQLDB, H2 or Apache Derby.

Comment: Thank you, just to clarify, besides sqlite, is there no way I can really do this?

Comment: I was wondering if I may import the sql db file into my eclipse application, before exporting the entire project as an executable file?